# SQL trigger compiling but I get an error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sql-insert, sqltransaction

I created a trigger in SQL and it compiles ok but when I run an insert it I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01403: no data found  
ORA-06512: at "EOCRIBIN.SHIPMENT_CAPACITY", line 5  
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EOCRIBIN.SHIPMENT_CAPACITY'  
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"  
*Cause:  No data was found from the objects.  
*Action: There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

Here is the trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Shipment_capacity
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE on SHIPMENT_TYPE FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  NOT_ENOUGH_CAPACITY EXCEPTION;
  WEIGHT INTEGER;
BEGIN

  SELECT VolumeCapacity
    INTO WEIGHT
    FROM shipment_type
   WHERE ShipmentType = :NEW.ShipmentType;

  IF WEIGHT > :new.WeightCapacity THEN
    RAISE NOT_ENOUGH_CAPACITY;
  END IF;

  EXCEPTION 
  WHEN NOT_ENOUGH_CAPACITY THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-200003,'Volume capacity exceeds weight limit');
END;
```

The table consists of the following :

```
CREATE TABLE SHIPMENT_TYPE
(
    ShipmentType varchar(25) primary key, 
    VolumeCapacity INT, 
    WeightCapacity INT, 
    Temperature float
);
```

Any idea why this error is happening?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your `select` statement?  If `ShipmentType` is the primary key, it looks like you just want to check `if :new.VolumeCapacity > :new.weightCapacity then`.  That doesn't seem like a particularly reasonable check to make.  I would guess that you really want to query a different table to get something to compare against.

Comment: Think that worked actually. I was following an example that's why I had the select but that makes sense cheers

Answer (score 2):

I think your select query return Nothing.  You can catch the exception with

```
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     --whatever you want to do when the error appear
END;
```